# Eclipse JFrame error

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, jframe

I'm getting this error with Eclipse. Any ideas why?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    JFrame frame;
    frame.setTitle("Elevator build 11");
    frame.setPositionRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You have to initialize the `frame` variable, something like `JFrame frame = new JFrame();`

Comment: And you need to be interacting with the object from within an executable context (ie a method)

Comment: Trying to compile your code would yield the actual error(s). Also, hovering your mouse over the red error marks should show a tooltip with a relevant message. @MadProgrammer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needs to be inside of a method. Try putting it inside of a main method. Also, you need to instantiate your frame first.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(); //instantiate frame
        // set the title
        // set the position
        // set it visible
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in your code:

- You need a method to place your code in. You should use the main method, since this is the method invoked by Java to start your program.
- You need to initialize the variable `frame` with a new instance of `JFrame`.
- There is no method called `setPositionRelativeTo` in the class `JFrame`. It is called `setLocationRelativeTo`.
- I also added some more method calls that might be helpful. `setSize` sets the window size, while `setDefaultCloseOperation` tells the `frame` what it should do when the window is closed. Here, `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` stands for exit the program when the window is closed.

Here is the complete code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleTest {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```